# synchronize an onprem fileshare to a sharepoint online site collection using powershell and Microsof RestAPI

Tags: powershell, rest, sharepoint, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to work out a powershell script that:

- retrieves an accesstoken (MSAL) to access (read/write) a sharepoint online site with subsites and documents. Preferably the Azure APP-registration ServicePrincipal can be granted access to just that site and access the sharepoint site/files without giving consent to the whole sharepoint environment. I don't know if that is possible currently as I can only grant application permission to files.readwrite.all and sites.readwrite.all. I do not see anything like files.readwrite.shared to grant access only to sites/collections that the serviceprincipal has access to. Anyone done this? I currently use the MSAL.PS powershell module to get a token using an AppRegistration with the admin-consented readwrite.all access but would like to limit that. The code for this is now:

  Import-Module MSAL.PS;
  $clientid = "my-appreg-client-id";
  $tenantID = 'my-tenant-id';
  $thumbPrint = 'certificate-thumbprint';
  $ClientCertificate = Get-Item "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$thumbPrint";
  $myAccessToken = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientID -TenantId $tenantID -ClientCertificate
  $ClientCertificate;
- The script will read all files and folders from an UNC-share and build a file-collection of the onprem files. That part of the code is in place using a Get-ChildItem call to the UNC filetree.
- Then, after getting the token, I need to get the current available files in the sharepoint online site document library structure and store that in a variable/hashtable which I can use to perform lookups between the onprem filecollection and the presence of those files and (sub)folders in the sharepoint site. If a folder does not yet exist I need to create that sharepoint folder and if a file is not yet present or the onprem version is newer I need to upload that file into sharepoint.

I have a script that does this using the old sharepoint.client.dll libraries but those support only basic authentication which will be unavailable any time soon for accessing the MS Online environment. So now I am searching for code to do this using the Microsoft Graph Api or other Rest API call. I am already struggling to get the contents of a site file collection so I hope that this generic problem description is enough to get some hints and tips/resources to get going.

Many thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use. I'm using powershell in Linux.

```
    ## Get the Token
    $clientId = "Application (Client) ID"
    $clientSecret = "Client secret"
    $tenantName = "TenantName.onmicrosoft.com"
    
    $tokenBody = @{
    
        Grant_Type    = 'client_credentials'
        Scope         = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
        Client_Id     = $clientId
        Client_Secret = $clientSecret
    }
    
    $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $tokenBody -ErrorAction Stop
    
    $headers = @{
    
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $($tokenResponse.access_token)"
        "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    }
    
    ## Use the SharePoint groups ObjectID. From this we'll get the drive ID.
    $site_objectid = "Groups ObjectID"
    
    ## Create all the folders on the SharePoint site first. I've set microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior below to fail because I never want to rename or replace folders.

    # Set the base directory. 
    $baseDirectory = "/test"
        $directories = get-childItem -path $baseDirectory -recurse -directory
    
        foreach ($directory in $directories) {
        $URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$site_objectid/sites/root"
    $subsite_ID = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Uri $URL -Method Get).ID
    
    $URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$subsite_ID/drives"
    $Drives = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Uri $URL -Method Get
    
    $Document_drive_ID = ($Drives.value | Where-Object { $_.name -eq 'Documents' }).id
            $createFolderURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/$Document_drive_ID/items/root:{0}:/children"  -f $directory.parent.FullName
            $file = $directory.Name
            
            $uploadFolderRequestBody = @{
                name= "$file"
                folder = @{}
                "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior"= "fail"
            } | ConvertTo-Json
    
            invoke-restMethod -headers $headers -method Post -body $uploadFolderRequestBody -contentType "application/json" -uri $createFolderURL
        }
    
    ## Upload the files. I'm only adding files that are 4 days old or less because I run the script every 3 days for backup. 
    ## These are set in the $sharefiles variable. To upload all files just remove everything after the pipe.
    
    $sharefiles = get-childItem  $baseDirectory -recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-4)}
        foreach ($sharefile in $sharefiles) {
    $Filepath = $sharefile.FullName
    $URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$site_objectid/sites/root"
    $subsite_ID = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Uri $URL -Method Get).ID
    
    $URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$subsite_ID/drives"
    $Drives = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Uri $URL -Method Get
    
    $Document_drive_ID = ($Drives.value | Where-Object { $_.name -eq 'Documents' }).id
    $Filename = $sharefile.Name
    
    $upload_session = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/$Document_drive_ID/root:{0}/$($Filename):/createUploadSession" -f $sharefile.directory.FullName
    
    $upload_session_url = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $upload_session -Headers $headers -Method Post).uploadUrl
    
    ## We'll upload files in chunks.
    
    $ChunkSize = 62259200
    $file = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo($Filepath)
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($Filepath)
    $buffer = New-Object -TypeName Byte[] -ArgumentList $ChunkSize
    $position = 0
    $counter = 0
    
    Write-Host "ChunkSize: $ChunkSize" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Write-Host "BufferSize: $($buffer.Length)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    
    $moreData = $true
    
    
    While ($moreData) {
        #Read a chunk
        $bytesRead = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
        $output = $buffer
        If ($bytesRead -ne $buffer.Length) {
            #no more data to be read
            $moreData = $false
            #shrink the output array to the number of bytes
            $output = New-Object -TypeName Byte[] -ArgumentList $bytesRead
            [Array]::Copy($buffer, $output, $bytesRead)
            Write-Host "no more data" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
        #Upload the chunk
        $Header = @{
            'Content-Range'  = "bytes $position-$($position + $output.Length - 1)/$($file.Length)"
        }
    
        Write-Host "Content-Range  = bytes $position-$($position + $output.Length - 1)/$($file.Length)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        #$position = $position + $output.Length - 1
        $position = $position + $output.Length
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $upload_session_url -Body $output -Headers $Header -SkipHeaderValidation
        #Increment counter
        $counter++
    }
    
    $reader.Close()
}
```